# How to extract Freebase Data Dump for a particular domains?

Tags: dns, freebase

I don't want to downloaded the 250G dump of freebase data. I don't need so big data. I want to extract a small subset of the data (a small domain). This small subset will make my iterations faster and easier.

Can somebody solve my problem?

Comment: You menace you are want some number of rows only

Comment: a domain data(like film or music)

Comment: I want to use a special domain data to develop a visual tool,this tool can help people to find information in a special domain.This is my graduate paper.

Answer (score 1):

The latest (and last) Freebase dump from the summer is under 30GB, not 250GB.  Most computers will be faster dealing with compressed than uncompressed data, so you should leave it compressed before processing.

zgrep is a good way to filter text files for specific patterns.  If you wanted to get fancy, you could use a small program which decompresses the data and searches for subject entities which meet your criteria.

The dump files are sorted in subject order, so all predicates for a given subject will be adjacent, simplifying the processing (you only need to buffer a small amount of data while you decide whether to include a particular subject in your filtered subset).